# Chameleon UIWebView can't focus

Tags: ios, macos, osx-chameleon

Using a UIWebView, the website cannot take focus. Clicking on a text box does nothing, and highlighting text is grayed out.

Comment: This question (not stated) is incredibly vague. If you want an answer, please provide more context. For example, how are you setting up the UIWebview, what website are you loading, is it all sites or just that one, etc.

Comment: It first appeared in an app I was porting, however reducing it to the bare minimum shows that even the most basic example causes this problem. It's all sites.